# Same .tex files can be compiled in one device but not other

Tags: compiling, texstudio

There's a rather curious situation that I'm facing: I was happily using my tex studio for months and everything was fine. Today I opened a .tex file where it uses fitch-style proofs, and after compiling I keep getting all sorts of errors -- even my good old files that I was working with before this. Also, it doesn't show the outcome in my compiler, but it does produce a pdf file in the folder. It seems that I have messed up with something while trying to make the fitch proofs work. Notice that the same files that I can't compile now can be compiled on my other laptop, using the same compiler, namely TEXstudio.

For sampling, I'm copying here the things the appear before the documents begin:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=apa,
citestyle=authoryear]
{biblatex}
\addbibresource{hom.bib}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{color}   %May be necessary if you want to color links
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=black,
    filecolor=black,
    linkcolor=black,
    urlcolor=black
}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{array,amsthm,amssymb,amsmath,enumitem}
\newcounter{rowcount}
\newenvironment{listproof}
{\setcounter{rowcount}{0}%
    \begin{proof}\mbox{}\\*
        \begin{tabular}[b]{
                @{%
                    \stepcounter{rowcount}%
                    %     \makebox[\dimexpr\leftmargini-\labelsep][r]{(\alph{rowcount})}\hspace{\labelsep}}
                    \makebox[\leftmargini][r]{(\arabic{rowcount})\hspace{\labelsep}}}
                ll@{}
            }%
        }
        {\end{tabular}\end{proof}}


\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\theoremstyle{theorem}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{excercise}{Excercise}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}
\usepackage[left=4cm, right=4cm, top=3cm]{geometry}


\newcommand{\lev}{\mathrm{l}}
\newcommand{\ord}{\mathrm{o}}
\newcommand{\proptype}{\langle\rangle}
\newcommand{\indtype}{e}
\newcommand{\q}{‘}
\newcommand{\qq}{“}
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm very new to this -- plain English explanations will be especially appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome. In principle it doesn't really matter that you use TeXstudio in both computers, what matters is the underlying collection of programs and packages, usually called a TeX distribution. In addition to TeXstudio you will have probably installed either MikTeX, MacTeX or TeX Live. These are the most common TeX distributions in use. In some cases a file won't work on a different system if the packages on that system are either older or newer. I can't guess exactly what's going on in your case though, perhaps if you edit the question to include the actual errors you get, someone else can.

Comment: you have not really given enough information but add `\listfiles` to your preamble and run it on both machines and compare the file versions in the list that is printed at the end

Comment: unrelated but don't load color after xcolor (xcolor already loaded it) don't specify amssymb and amsmath twice (second usepackage doesn't do anything) but if you showed your error someone may be able to help

Comment: Thanks all. Here are the errors:

Line 30: File ended while scanning use of \@argdef. \usepackage.
Line 125: Environment proof undefined. \begin{proof}.
Line 127: \begin{document} ended by \end{proof}. \end{proof}.

These three are red (error). But there are yellow ones (warning) as well, mostly targeting my citations. As you can see, I'm using biblatex. (In the PDF file that's being produced, the citations aren't printed and loo bizarre on the spots where cited: e.g., instead of Quine (1950), it shows 'quine_two_dogmas_1950')

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I have installed TeX Maker, I think.

Comment: Does this info help or do you need other info as well?

Comment: Texmaker is an editor, not related to this. Your larex distribution is listed at the top of the lig file. Please post the entire log file in your question. Additionally complete your example to something others have a chance to compile on their systems. Right now it is just a preamble